# A problem with placing a formula at the left side of the page

Tags: amsmath, typography

I'm having  the integral of a function over path C1 and C2  .I want to have both c1 and c2 on the left side of my page but anything I use doesn't work . 
I tried to put it with the align* , itemize , [], and many other things , but the result was always the same . 
what should I do to put them on the left side of the page ?

```
\documentclass{article}‎


‎\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}‎ 
‎ ‎‎
\begin{document}
‎‎\begin{align*}‎
‎C_1:  x= y‎ ‎\implies ‎z(t) =‎ ‎x(t)+ ‎iy(t)= ‎(1+i)t ‎‎\qquad 0 ‎‎‎‎\leqslant t ‎‎‎‎\leqslant ‎1‎‎ ‎‎\\
f[z(t)] = Re z(t) = t, ‎\quad ‎dz =‎ ‎(1+i)dt ‎ ‎‎\\‎
\int ‎Re z‎ ‎dz  =‎‎ ‎(1+i) ‎\int_‎{0}^{1} t‎ ‎dt = ‎‎‎‎\frac{1}{2}(1+i)‎‎ \\‎‎[1cm]‎
C_2:  ‎‎z(t)  =‎‎ ‎‎
‎\left\{\!\! \begin{array}{l}‎
t ‎‎‎‎\qquad  ‎‎0‎ \leqslant t \leqslant 1‎‎ ‎‎\\‎‎‎
1+i(t-1) ‎‎\qquad‎‎ a \leqslant 1 \leqslant 2‎
‎\end{array}\right‎. ‎ ‎‎\\‎
\int_{c_2} Rez dz = \int_{0}^{1} t dt  + i \int_{1}^{2}  dt = ‎\frac{1}{2} +‎ i‎ ‎‎
‎\end{align*}‎

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you use `align*` or a related environment of `amsmath`, use `&` as alignment marker. Usually this is done right before a relation symbol, for aligning at the relation symbol.

In some amsmath environments you could use several `&` in a line for several columns or several alignment points, respectivels. In this case amsmath works also as column delimiter.

Here, you could use `alignat` for a numbered multiline formula with several alignments, or the block environment `alignedat`. Here is an example, which does the required alignment. The argument to `alignedat` means the number of aligned columns. Have a look at the [`amsmath` user's guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) for a complete explanation how those environment work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    &C_1:  &x= y \implies z(t) = x(t)+ iy(t)= (1+i)t \qquad 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1 \\
    &&f[z(t)] = Re z(t) = t, \quad dz = (1+i)dt  \\
    &&\int Re z dz  = (1+i) \int_{0}^{1} t dt = \frac{1}{2}(1+i) \\[1cm]
    &C_2:  &z(t)  =
      \left\{\!\! \begin{array}{l}
      t \qquad  0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1 \\
      1+i(t-1) \qquad a \leqslant 1 \leqslant 2
      \end{array}\right.  \\
    &&\int_{c_2} Rez dz = \int_{0}^{1} t dt  + i \int_{1}^{2}  dt = \frac{1}{2} + i
  \end{alignedat}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned equations]

You could also simply use an `array` environment and its flexible column alignment options, since here you don't need numbering and no alignment on relation symbols.

Comment: I used it but as your picture there is too much black space between c2 and the formula . Is there any other environment at which I van have what I want ?

Comment: @Negin The space is because of the right alignment. You could add further `&` symbols (see amsmath manual). Regarding another environment, I updated my answer.